# XPath: find x and y, where y is not a child of x

Tags: html, xpath

```
<p>
  text
</p>
<p>
  <span>text</span>
</p>
<p>
  <p>text</p>
</p>

<span>text</span> 
<span><p>text</p></span>
<span><span></span></span>
```

I'm looking to select outer elements in all these cases, so once it selects and outer element, it should ignore the inner element and move ahead.

1. Select `p`
2. Select `p` but not inner `span`
3. Select outer `p`
4. Select `span`
5. Select `span` but not inner `p`
6. select outer `span`

I tried this:

```
//p//*[not(span)] | //span//*[not(p)]
```

.. but not getting the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//p[not(ancestor::p|ancestor::span)] | //span[not(ancestor::p|ancestor::span)]
```

The above expression would return all outer-most `p` and `span` elements. By *outer-most* I mean, those elements that isn't contained in any other `p` or `span` element.

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/1iqd-TIQo)</kbd>**

---

The above expression can be shortened as follow :

```
//*[self::p|self::span][not(ancestor::p|ancestor::span)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I do need to get the outer-most so I don't get any of those twice.